# Is it possible to use gdb and nested qemu virtual machine to debug linux user space programs and host hypervisor simultaneously?

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, gdb, virtualization

I want to debug a user application running in a nested virtualization environment.
So I build a static version of QEMU and run it with KVM support.
I call the first VM running by QEMU as host VM, and then running another QEMU inner the host VM and named it with guest VM. Finally I can run a user application inner the guest VM.
The environment is work correctly and the question now is that, how can I debug such a environment and how to follow the control flow in user application and KVM in host VM simultaneously?

UP TO NOW, I use build in kvm instead of kvm module, and use gdb to attach the host VM. After add-symbol-file [the user runnable binary] and set hardware breakpoint by 'hb main', the control flow can correctly stop in the user application's main function, but the gdb can not read any data from any virtual address and just return msg as bellow:

```
(gdb) x main                                                                                                                                                                      
0x404091 <main>:        Cannot access memory at address 0x404091
```

Can anyone give some suguesstions about how to deal with this error?

Comment: Interesting, I would never have thought to use a gdb instance in the host to debug a process in the guest.

Comment: Gdb uses the ptrace system call to access the memory of the process being debugged. Obviously since the process isn’t running under the same OS, that’s not going to work.

Comment: Gdb has a way to debug on a remote system using either a serial or network connection to talk to the remote. That’s what you’re going to want to do: treat the guest as a remote system.

Comment: @prl thanks for your suggestions, but I try to trace the whole control flow from guest user application, to host kvm hypervisors. Seems that just treat the guest as a remote system can only give me the ability to follow the app but no help for host debuging. For the host kvm can read current cr3 & ept, so there can be a way for host ptrace to use this two level table to access the correct address. Do you know which file should I modify or some documentations mention about ptrace memory access? THX!!!